# What does "There's no escaping reason, no denying purpose" mean?

Tags: meaning, quotations

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), after Oracle left the scene, Agent Smith says to Neo:

> Agent Smith: But as you well know, appearances can be deceiving...which brings me back to the reason
> why we're here. We're not here because we're free. We're here because we are not free.
> **There's no escaping reason, no denying purpose**. Because as we both know,
> without purpose...we would not exist.

What does "There's no escaping reason, no denying purpose" mean?

Comment: It means "It is impossible to escape reason, impossible to deny purpose". There are some examples at [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/there-s-no-knowing-saying-telling-etc). We sometimes say, "There's no knowing/saying/telling (who will win the race)" to mean "It is impossible to know/say/tell (who will win the race)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *There's no escaping reason, no denying purpose.*

The sentence is referring back to the word *reason* in a previous sentence:

> *Which brings me back to the **reason** why we're here*.

The sentence uses *reason* and *purpose* as synonyms, referring forward to the word *purpose* in the following sentence.

When he says "there's no escaping* reason and purpose, he's saying, in effect, that that is what they must now deal with together.